# authenticate javascript front ends

Tags: javascript

I going to build my first hybrid web application(go - angular js) and I want to authenticate my angular js front end to my back end.
But I can't put any secret key into my front end code because any body can find that secret key by reading my front end source code and find that secret key.
How can I authenticate my angular js front end (or any other JavaScript front end framework) without saving any secret key on my source code?

Update: Actually I looking for some thing like developer secret key, but I don't need to save it somewhere visible for anyone.

Comment: I wrote a blog post about this http://jonsamwell.com/url-route-authorization-and-security-in-angular/

Comment: @JonSamwell My problem is not how to authenticate user, my problem is how to authenticate my front end. Something like giving a developer secret key, but this time I can't simply put it in my source code.

Comment: Use OAuth2 protocol or social logins - you could look at this https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v3

Comment: Depends what you are doing, if you have a user account system then for each user you can create a session via the node server and when they login you add a flag to the session saying they are logged in. Then on secure endpoints you add middleware which checks that they have a session with the correct flag.

Comment: @DominicTobias I don't want authenticate for my user, I want it for my front end! For Example I don't want to others use my back end api and I just want to my official angular js app can use it!

Comment: @AmanMazdae Then in that case, no you cannot have a secure front end without user input - think about it - everything on the client is visible to anyone, the only way you can set up a secure connection is if the client enters something that nobody else knows (e.g. username/password)

Comment: Well, you CAN at least make sure that if someone is using your backend *using a web browser*, it has to come through your website. (You can do this by checking Origin headers, and similar) So if you're making Google Maps, no one can just include your map info in their website without permission. But if someone is writing a Perl script and can write headers how they like, Dominic is pretty much right.

Comment: @ArmanMazdaee By virtue of the fact that a human will be interacting with your front end, you need to authenticate the user. Now, if you want to authenticate your application similar to how you would authenticate a Google JS Client or something, this needs to be done on top of that user authentication. You can go as simple as providing a shared key between the app and the API (probably not a good idea), or you can go to more advanced authentication techniques. OAuth2 has already been suggested.

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte In oauth2 I still need to save some secret key like application secret key on my angular js code?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot prevent someone from dumping every request you made to your server and replay them after modifying them.

Like you say, you can sign your requests but the key you'll use will be visible in your Angular code. It's a common problem and even mobile applications are [vulnerables](http://arstechnica.com/security/2014/06/secret-keys-stashed-in-google-play-apps-pose-risk-to-android-users-developers/) to it.

The only thing you can do is to make some verification server-side. Like the request domain origin or the user-agent and secure everyone of your end-point. Remember, you should not trust the client.

Comment: I don't understand it. May you give me some link to learn about it more please?

Comment: You can see this answer on StackOverflow about large web application written in Go and how they are secured : http://stackoverflow.com/a/18240299/3680412.